# Is there a collision between lmodern and mathptmx?

Tags: fonts

I have realized that in my document there are multiple fonts loaded:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern} % first = lmodern
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} % second = Times
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

My question is: Is there a collision between these two? I found that generally the second font loaded overwrites the first one, but not always. Currently I am not sure if my document is created in Times or lmodern.

Comment: Generally speaking the last font package wins, but if the involved font packages define different font families (for example the first package defines a roman and a sans serif font, the second package defines a monospace font and the third package defines only a roman font), you may end up with a mixture of different faces (but again, the last package to define the particular face wins, in the example you'd get the sans serif of package 1, the monospace font from package 2 and the roman font from package 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you load `mathptmx` as second it will set the roman (serif) font. You can check this with

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern} % first = lmodern
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % second = Times
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\begin{document}
 aaaaaaaaa
\end{document}
```

The log-file will show at the end a times font:

```
    /texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb
```

The sans serif font and the mono font will be from `lmodern`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just a tiny follow-up question: Would you recommend to deactivate `lmodern`? Sounds a bit odd to me to have a mix between the two.

Comment: It depends what fonts you want to use as sans serif and typewriter. Try it out and look if you like the result. But if you want a times variant as serif, I wouldn't use mathptmx but newtx, that is newer and maintained.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand your code, but sometimes I just don't understand English language .

Comment: Thanks very helpful.